# Выражения ' if ' - PHP

Tags: php

Можно ли заменить этот код

```
<?php
$error = array();
$array = explode(',', $string);
if (count($array) == 0) {
    array_push($error, 'OSHIBKA');
    exit;
}
?>
```

На следующий

```
<?php
$error = array();
$array = explode(',', $string);
count($array) !== 0 or array_push($error, 'OSHIBKA') and exit;
?>
```

Можно ли сделать что-то подобное?

Comment: а зачем? _Можно ли сделать что-то подобное?_ - попробуйте

Comment: Пытаюсь всевозможными способами сократить код страницы. Слишком уж много весит. И если будет необходимость что-то изменить в исходном коде, то не искать 1,5 часа..

Comment: Если надо сократить код страницы, подумайте лучше о подходящем разбиении на функции.

Comment: Весит что? сам код или сгенерированный html? посчитайте сколько символов в случае удачи вы сокращаете таким способом, за счет читаемости

Comment: Полностью согласен с @Grundy. Читаемость кода - это параметр, на который стоит ориентироваться, в случае, если Вы хотите позже что-то в нем искать. Часто в хорошо структурированном полотне легче найти нужное место, чем в 10 строках кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой код сработает.

```
<?php
$error = array();
$array = explode(',', $string);
count($array) != 0 or array_push($error, 'OSHIBKA') and exit;
?>
```

Comment: вы убрали `if () { }` - 8 символов, плюс переносы строк - пускай 12, и добавили `or`, `and` - 5 символов и пробелы вокруг каждого - 9 - выгода в 5 символов. стоило ли?

Comment: почти. просто я не весь код сдесь представил. Там у меня: if (... and ... or ... and...) { do {...}...}. В общем получше стало.

Comment: в таком случае возможно :-) все равно не совсем понятно что именно за вес вы хотели снизить

Comment: @Lesperanza Я вообще не понял как у вас работает код. explode всегда создает хотя бы один элемент, даже если строка пустая, т.е. count  никогда не равен нулю

Comment: @Mike, а если строка - null? или какой там аналог в php?

Comment: @Grundy Специально проверил, null и false вместо строки так же дают 1 пустой элемент в массиве

Comment: @Mike тогда понятно почему работает :-) первое условие всегда срабатывает :-) и ошибки никогда нет :)